# Unable to install a 'Minor Upgrade' msi in Installshield X?

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, installshield

Hmmm..Again its the same issue in Installshield..I am using Installshield X version and I am getting the error when I try to install a minor upgraded version of MSI.I Googled a lot followed the steps to perform a minor upgrade.

**STEPS I FOLLOW **

As this is a minor upgrade (Jus a file updation)
I changed the Package Code(generated a new one) and Product Version (incremented 1 from the previous) !!

**ERROR I GET **

I get an error "Another version of this product is already installed.Installation of this version cannot continue.To configure or remove the existing version of this product, Use Add/Remove programs on the control panel"

I FOUND THIS AS A COMMON ERROR AND THERE WAS A SOLUTION FROM THE BELOW GIVEN LINK
http://www.msigeek.com/1256/how-do-you-create-a-minor-upgrade-for-an-application-using-installshield

**SOLUTION WITHOUT ERROR**

I still remember the Upgrade working perfectly few months back for me as I use to get a Pop-up message saying that this a an upgrade...
I did not perform any extra commandline statements or any other step expect the Package Code and Product Version

**SOLUTION I NEED**

Is there any thing to be done other than the regular process which I follow to install the new MSI on a system which has the previous version MSI ??

**DETAILS TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR**

FIRST MSI
Installshield Version - X
Product Version - 5.1
Package Code - Same
Upgrade Code - Same
Product Code - Same
Upgrades - Major (The minor upgrade worked for me wid out creating a upgrade for minor)

SECOND MSI
Installshield Version - X
Product Version - 5.2
Package Code - Generated new
Upgrade Code - Same
Product Code - Same
Upgrades - Major (The minor upgrade worked for me wid out creating a upgrade for minor)

huh..Installshield Pros would have experienced this so replies please !! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Minor upgrades are invoked using the command msiexec /i foo.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus.  Since you don't want your users to have to type this you need a bootstrapper to do it for you.  InstallShield can generate a setup.exe that detects this state and does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Also its good see that there is an option for me to avoid the error for all the users !! I know it would be bad if I ask you how to do it !!! :D...But you have to help me in this Issue...Can you explain me how to do it successfully !! Thanks in advance !!